# Linkedlist with multi attributes

Tags: java, linked-list, recursive-datastructures

```
public class Payment { 
  public String fromPerson; // name of Person paying
  public String toPerson; // name of Person receiving payment
  public double amount; // amount payed
  public Timestamp timestamp; // unique time stamp (provided at the time of creation)
  public Payment next; // reference to next payment in appropriate Ledger Linked List

  /**
   * Basic empty constructor for a payment
   */

  public Payment() {
    // Provided - not to be changed
    this.fromPerson = null;
    this.toPerson = null;
    this.amount = 0;
    this.timestamp = null;
    this.next = null;
  } 
  /**
   * Payment constructor with all necessary fields to be inserted in Ledger
   * 
   * @param fromPerson is the person paying
   * @param toPerson   is the person receiving the payment
   * @param amount     is the amount payed
   * @param timestamp  is time at creation of payment
   * @param next       is the next payment
   */

  public Payment(String fromPerson, String toPerson, double amount, Payment next) {
    // Provided - not to be changed
    this.fromPerson = fromPerson;
    this.toPerson = toPerson;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.timestamp = new Timestamp(); // time stamp is automatically set at creation
    this.next = next;
  }

  /**
   * A Payment is valid if it is done between registered persons provided in the
   * array persons
   * 
   * 
   * @param persons - array of persons who can make and receive payment
   * 
   * @return true if the Payment is valid based on the criteria listed above,
   *         false otherwise
   */
  public boolean isValid(String[] persons) {
 
  }

}
```

Test Case

```
 public void testPaymentIsValid() {

    assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofMillis(1000), () -> {

      String[] registeredPeopleV1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
      String[] registeredPeopleV2 = { "Brian", "Thomas", "Elizabeth", "Sakura", "Lucy", "Tyson" };

      // Case 1: Payment from unregistered person

      Payment invalid1 = new Payment("t", "a", 10.0, null);
      assertFalse(invalid1.isValid(registeredPeopleV1));

      Payment invalid2 = new Payment("Gray", "Brian", 4.0, null);
      assertFalse(invalid2.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      // Case 2: Payment to unregistered person
      Payment invalid3 = new Payment("a", "t", 10.0, null);
      assertFalse(invalid3.isValid(registeredPeopleV1));

      Payment invalid4 = new Payment("Brian", "Gray", 4.0, null);
      assertFalse(invalid4.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      // Case 3: Unregistered people involved in the payment
      Payment invalid5 = new Payment("Sai", "Mei", 22.1, null);
      assertFalse(invalid5.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      // Case 4: Valid payment between registered people
      Payment valid1 = new Payment("a", "b", 100.0, null);
      assertTrue(valid1.isValid(registeredPeopleV1));

      Payment valid2 = new Payment("Sakura", "Thomas", 20.0, null);
      assertTrue(valid2.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      Payment validCase = new Payment("sakura", "thomas", 220, null);
      assertTrue(validCase.isValid(registeredPeopleV2)); // The names should not be case-sensitive

      // Case 5: Payment whose next is NOT null (To ensure it only checks current
      // payment and NOT the next one)
      Payment valid3 = new Payment("Lucy", "Thomas", 20.0, valid2);
      assertTrue(valid3.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      Payment valid4 = new Payment("Lucy", "Thomas", 20.0, invalid2); // doesn't matter even if next payment is invalid
      assertTrue(valid4.isValid(registeredPeopleV2));

      Payment invalid6 = new Payment("t", "a", 10.0, valid1); // doesn't matter even if next payment is valid
      assertFalse(invalid6.isValid(registeredPeopleV1));

      Payment invalid7 = new Payment("t", "a", 10.0, invalid1);
      assertFalse(invalid7.isValid(registeredPeopleV1));

    });
    currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
  }
```

I am so confused about the input of the isValid method.
So the node here is Payment and the input for the isValid is String of person which part of the data that payment holds, how do I check all the person are in there?
Can a node hold more than 1 data ?

```
  public boolean isValid(String[] persons) {
    for(int i=0;i<persons.length;i++) {
      if(this.fromPerson.equals(persons[i])&&this.toPerson.equals(persons[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

This is what I have done but seems only returning false all the time.

Comment: The parameter to `isValid` is an _array_ of Strings. Since `isValid` is part of the Payment class, and the Payment class has `fromPerson` and `toPerson`, I would assume that the parameter `String[] persons` contains all of the valid persons, and indeed the documentation says "A Payment is valid if it is done between registered persons **provided in the array persons**"

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.  Why is the type in isValid an array of string?  Should it be an array of Persons?  Many other problems.  But you first need to fix at least isValid method.

Comment: Yes it would have to. In test case it given 2 String arrays contains valid persons. But how do I link payment class and String [] persons to check it is valid or not

Comment: The test case does not _give_ 2 String arrays; it _has_ 2 String arrays and it gives _one_ String array to `isValid` which is _either_ `registeredPeopleV1` or `registeredPeopleV2`

Comment: As for your question _"Can a node hold more than 1 data?"_ ... that would be using an object of some class. If you had a `Person` class that had first & last name, age, etc. you could, for example, pass an array `Person[]` to isValid instead of Strings, and test if the person's age > 18 besides testing the name.

Comment: persons is just one of the parameter of Payment as seen in the constructor.In the isValid method how would I check whether it is valid or not as per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you meant.

What you want to do is search the string array contains names of persons to see if both to and from are in the array.

Here's a possible solution:

```
class Payment {
   String from, to;
   Payment(String f, String t){ from = f;  to = t;}
   
   boolean isValid(String[] persons) {
     if (from.equals(to)) return false;  
     boolean toFound = false;
     boolean fromFound = false;
     for(String p: persons){
        if (to.equals(p))   toFound = true;
        if (from.equals(p)) fromFound = true;
     }
     return toFound && fromFound;
  }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] persons = {"a", "b", "c"};
        Payment[] payments = { 
            new Payment("a", "b"), new Payment("a", "a"),
            new Payment("a", "x"), new Payment("x", "y"),
            new Payment("b", "c")};
        for(Payment p: payments)
          System.out.println(p.isValid(persons));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Were you able to tell why my one isn't working tho...

Comment: In your isValid(), fromPerson and toPerson exists and are the same person, then you return true.  otherwise, it will always return false.

Comment: Aha, thank you so much. Now I see the problem, they were both under same index before so I should separate them into 2 cases. Appreciate it!

Comment: With such small _registered people_ arrays for testing this doesn't matter ... but you could add a line in your for-loop after `if (from.equals(p)) fromFound = true;` to quit the loop rather than keep looking to the end of the array as soon as both are found: `if (toFound && fromFound) break;` — and skip unneeded string compares by doing `if (! toFound && to.equals(p)) toFound = true;`